# Asynchronously remove JSON object from screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to create a single-page app that pulls information from a JSON file, displays it on the screen, and perform a few actions.

Right now, I have all of the information being displayed on the screen properly: http://jsfiddle.net/rcsayf7t/3/

I need the "Remove" button to asynchronously remove the JSON object from the screen when it's clicked, but unfortunately have no idea how to go about accomplishing it.

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            <th scope="col">Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Message</th>
            <th scope="col">Date</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tweets-result"></tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
// helper function for formatting date
function formatDate(date) {
    var dateSplit = date.split(" ");
    var displayDate = dateSplit[0] + ", " + dateSplit[1] + " " + dateSplit[2];

    // return the result
    return displayDate;
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    // start ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/arlodesign/7d80edb6e801e92c977a/raw/24605c9e5de897f7877b9ab72af13e5b5a2e25eb/tweets.json",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            // store the JSON data
            var tweetData = $.parseJSON(data);

            // loop through json values and build the table
            $.each(tweetData.tweets, function (index, item) {
                $('.tweets-result').append(
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td><img src="' + item.profile_image_url + '" alt="@' + item.screen_name + ' avatar"></td>' +
                    '<td><a href="https://twitter.com/' + item.screen_name + '">@' + item.screen_name + '</a></td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.text + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + formatDate(item.created_at) + '</td>' +
                    '<td>Remove</td>' +
                    '</tr>');

                    // WHEN YOU CLICK "REMOVE", THE TWEET SHOULD
                    // ASYNCHRONOUSLY BE REMOVED FROM THE SCREEN
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: define `asynchronously remove` and the full behavior and events you are expecting

Comment: Did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rcsayf7t/4/)

Just add the following inside ajax success:

```
$('.remove_row').click(function(){
      $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

and the following code as remove attribute:

```
class="remove_row"
```

Full JS (read my comments):

```
// helper function for formatting date
function formatDate(date) {
    var dateSplit = date.split(" ");
    var displayDate = dateSplit[0] + ", " + dateSplit[1] + " " + dateSplit[2];

    // return the result
    return displayDate;
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    // start ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/arlodesign/7d80edb6e801e92c977a/raw/24605c9e5de897f7877b9ab72af13e5b5a2e25eb/tweets.json",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            // store the JSON data
            var tweetData = $.parseJSON(data);

            // loop through json values and build the table
            $.each(tweetData.tweets, function (index, item) {
                $('.tweets-result').append(
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td><img src="' + item.profile_image_url + '" alt="@' + item.screen_name + ' avatar"></td>' +
                    '<td><a href="https://twitter.com/' + item.screen_name + '">@' + item.screen_name + '</a></td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.text + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + formatDate(item.created_at) + '</td>' +
                    '<td class="remove_row">Remove</td>' + // ## Here add the class remove_row
                    '</tr>');

                    // WHEN YOU CLICK "REMOVE", THE TWEET SHOULD
                    // ASYNCHRONOUSLY BE REMOVED FROM THE SCREEN
            });

            //## Here assign the even on click for the remove button
            $('.remove_row').click(function(){
               $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });
        }
    });


});
```